# R read data with unformated separation

Tags: r

I use the R language, and I need to read a different files with different separation formats, like:

file1.txt

```
1.2 2.3\n
1.3 3.4\n
3.3 3.5\n
```

for this is simple, I only use:

`mytable <- read.table("file1.txt", header=FALSE, sep=" ")`
but,I also have this unformated data file (different separation):
file2.txt

```
 1.2  1.3 \n
 1.1  2.3 \n
 3.2  1.2 \n
```

obs.: the "\n" is only to show where is the line breaker.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [R manua](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)l:

> If `sep = ""` (the default for `read.table`) the separator is "white space, that is one or more spaces, tabs, newlines or carriage returns.

You should be able to achive what you want by simply omitting the `sep` argument or, if you want to be more explicit, specifying an empty string for it: `read.table("file1.txt", header=FALSE, sep="")`